# Flip image horizontally with tween animation. No 3D

Tags: android, xml, animation, flip, tween

How can I flip horizontally an image with a tween animation in android? I don't desire a 3D effect. I only need to mirror the image.

Answer (score 0):

I guess negative values for scaleX or scaleY result in mirroring the image. If it's your case than you could animate scale from 1 to -1. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. It can be done this way, but I have some troubles alternating positive and negative values. Look at this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" > 

<!--     <alpha -->
<!--         android:duration="200" -->
<!--         android:fromAlpha="0" -->
<!--         android:startOffset="0" -->
<!--         android:toAlpha="1" /> -->

    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.4"
        android:toYScale="0.4" />

<!--     <alpha -->
<!--         android:duration="200" -->
<!--         android:fromAlpha="1" -->
<!--         android:startOffset="200" -->
<!--         android:toAlpha="0" /> -->
<!--     <alpha -->
<!--         android:duration="200" -->
<!--         android:fromAlpha="0" -->
<!--         android:startOffset="400" -->
<!--         android:toAlpha="1" /> -->

    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXScale="-0.4"
        android:fromYScale="0.4"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="400"
        android:toXScale="-0.8"
        android:toYScale="0.8" />

<!--     <alpha -->
<!--         android:duration="200" -->
<!--         android:fromAlpha="1" -->
<!--         android:startOffset="600" -->
<!--         android:toAlpha="0" /> -->
<!--     <alpha -->
<!--         android:duration="200" -->
<!--         android:fromAlpha="0" -->
<!--         android:startOffset="800" -->
<!--         android:toAlpha="1" /> -->

    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXScale="0.8"
        android:fromYScale="0.8"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="800"
        android:toXScale="1.2"
        android:toYScale="1.2" />

<!--     <alpha -->
<!--         android:duration="200" -->
<!--         android:fromAlpha="1" -->
<!--         android:startOffset="1000" -->
<!--         android:toAlpha="0" /> -->
<!--     <alpha -->
<!--         android:duration="200" -->
<!--         android:fromAlpha="0" -->
<!--         android:startOffset="1200" -->
<!--         android:toAlpha="1" /> -->

    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXScale="-1.2"
        android:fromYScale="1.2"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="1200"
        android:toXScale="-1.6"
        android:toYScale="1.6" />

<!--     <alpha -->
<!--         android:duration="200" -->
<!--         android:fromAlpha="1" -->
<!--         android:startOffset="2400" -->
<!--         android:toAlpha="0" /> -->

</set>
```

This should generate an image that grows and flips some times... but it doesn't work. It only shows an image that grows some times... but without mirroring the image!

What I'm doing wrong?

EDITED----

Finally, I've found a way to make it work. I make the flip and resize in two parts. But I can't add more resizes, because it wouldn't show anything... try to uncomment the commented blocks and tell me why does it work in that way...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="false"> 

    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toAlpha="1" />

    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.4"
        android:toYScale="0.4" />


    <scale
        android:duration="1"
        android:fromXScale="0.4"
        android:fromYScale="0.4"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="400"
        android:toXScale="-0.4"
        android:toYScale="0.4" />
        <scale
        android:duration="399"
        android:fromXScale="-0.4"
        android:fromYScale="0.4"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="401"
        android:toXScale="-0.8"
        android:toYScale="0.8" />


        <scale
        android:duration="1"
        android:fromXScale="-0.8"
        android:fromYScale="0.8"
        android:pivotX="50%" 
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="800"
        android:toXScale="0.8"
        android:toYScale="0.8"/>
                <scale
        android:duration="399"
        android:fromXScale="0.8"
        android:fromYScale="0.8"
        android:pivotX="50%" 
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="801"
        android:toXScale="1.2"
        android:toYScale="1.2" />


<scale
        android:duration="1"
        android:fromXScale="1.2"
        android:fromYScale="1.2"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="1200"
        android:toXScale="-1.2"
        android:toYScale="1.2"/>
<scale
        android:duration="399"
        android:fromXScale="-1.2"
        android:fromYScale="1.2"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="1201"
        android:toXScale="-1.6"
        android:toYScale="1.6" />


<scale
        android:duration="1"
        android:fromXScale="-1.6"
        android:fromYScale="1.6"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="1600"
        android:toXScale="1.6"
        android:toYScale="1.6"/>
<scale
        android:duration="399"
        android:fromXScale="1.6"
        android:fromYScale="1.6"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="1601"
        android:toXScale="2"
        android:toYScale="2" />


<scale
        android:duration="1"
        android:fromXScale="2"
        android:fromYScale="2"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="2000"
        android:toXScale="-2"
        android:toYScale="2"/>
<scale
        android:duration="399"
        android:fromXScale="-2"
        android:fromYScale="2"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="2001"
        android:toXScale="-2.4"
        android:toYScale="2.4" />


<!-- <scale -->
<!--         android:duration="1" -->
<!--         android:fromXScale="-2.4" -->
<!--         android:fromYScale="2.4" -->
<!--         android:pivotX="50%" -->
<!--         android:pivotY="50%" -->
<!--         android:startOffset="2400" -->
<!--         android:toXScale="2.4" -->
<!--         android:toYScale="2.4" /> -->
<!-- <scale -->
<!--         android:duration="399" -->
<!--         android:fromXScale="2.4" -->
<!--         android:fromYScale="2.4" -->
<!--         android:pivotX="50%" -->
<!--         android:pivotY="50%" -->
<!--         android:startOffset="2401" -->
<!--         android:toXScale="2.8" -->
<!--         android:toYScale="2.8" /> -->


<!-- <scale -->
<!--         android:duration="1" -->
<!--         android:fromXScale="2.8" -->
<!--         android:fromYScale="2.8" -->
<!--         android:pivotX="50%" -->
<!--         android:pivotY="50%" -->
<!--         android:startOffset="2800" -->
<!--         android:toXScale="-2.8" -->
<!--         android:toYScale="2.8" /> -->
<!-- <scale -->
<!--         android:duration="399" -->
<!--         android:fromXScale="-2.8" -->
<!--         android:fromYScale="2.8" -->
<!--         android:pivotX="50%" -->
<!--         android:pivotY="50%" -->
<!--         android:startOffset="2801" -->
<!--         android:toXScale="-3.2" -->
<!--         android:toYScale="3.2" /> -->


    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:startOffset="2400"
        android:toAlpha="0" />

</set>
```